# Drawing SQL data into ASPX grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to make a simple ASP.NET page, which uses a external database as source of information. I have encountered a task that I cannot imagine how to solve. Here is the description of the task:

- there are 100 records in the database, having ID from 0 - 99
- each record contains the attribute "Colour" specifying the colour of a particular field
- the task is to create an aspx page with a grid of 10 x 10 fields. Retrieve the data from the database. Use the ID for correct placement of the field: ID % 10 specifies the column in the grid, ID % 100 specifies the row. Fill every cell in the grid with the specified colour.

To be more specific: I know, how to retrieve the data from the database, I just don't know, what to use, to draw the grid and fill it with colours. Could you give me some advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *[Table](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/01/24/html-tables-to-asp-net-table-controls.aspx)* control. 
Here is an example of how to add cells into table:

*aspx*

```
  <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

*Codebehind*

```
  TableRow row = new TableRow();

  TableCell cell = new TableCell();
  cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  cell.Text = "some text";
  row.Cells.Add(cell);
  Table1.Rows.Add(row);
```